# Problems extracting property names from an object (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects (I think!) and I need to extract the property name (for example "nickname") from a given object.

With

```
var VarObjAndValue = newArr[0];
```

I get the individual arrays (for example `Object { nickname: “jhonny” }`).

How can I now extract the property name "nickname" from the object above?

Listing the keys with

```
var listPropertyNames = Object.keys(newArr);
```

only provides sequential numbers from 0 to 6 rather than the desired keys names..

```
var StrToInclude = ["nickname", "name", "surname", "sex", "dob", "email", "phone"];
var newArr=[]; //Key name + its value

for (var i=0; i<StrToInclude.length; i++) {
  temp_obj = {};
  temp_obj[StrToInclude[i]] = document.getElementById(StrToInclude[i]).value;
  newArr.push(temp_obj);
}

console.log('newArr --> = ',newArr);
/**
 * newArr = [
 * { "nickname": “jhonny” },
 * { "name": “jonathan” },
 * { "surname": “ross” },
 * { "sex": “male” },
 * { "dob": “22/02/1984” },
 * { "email": “j@yahoo.com” },
 * { "phone": "123" }
 * ]
 */

var VarObjAndValue = newArr[0]; 
console.log('VarObjAndValue --> = ',VarObjAndValue); //if i=0 ----> Object { nickname: “jhonny” }

var VarObjAndValue = newArr[1]; 
console.log('VarObjAndValue --> = ',VarObjAndValue); //if i=1 ----> Object { name: "jonathan" }

var listPropertyNames = Object.keys(newArr);
console.log('listPropertyNames --> = ',listPropertyNames); //Array(7) [ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" ] (not useful for this...)
```

Comment: why do you have to construct an array with objects of different schema ? I mean why not to use a single top level object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close to getting the right answer. Since newArr is an Array, the keys are numeric keys. All you have to do is go through each element is the Array of Objects to extract the keys. Something like this should do nicely:

```
for(let i = 0;i<newArr.length;i++){
    console.log(Object.keys(newArr[i])); //Will go through the whole array and give you the keys of every object in it
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
newArr.map(obj => Object.keys(obj)).flat()
```

or `newArr.map(obj => Object.keys(obj)[0])`
or from **dave**'s comment

```
newArr.reduce((keys, o) => [...keys, ...Object.keys(o)], [])
```

gives you all property names as an array

Not sure if this is what you want, but you have already gotten those property names in `StrToInclude`

```js
const newArr =
                [
                  {
                    "nickname": "jhonny"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "jonathan"
                  },
                  {
                    "surname": "ross"
                  },
                  {
                    "sex": "male"
                  },
                  {
                    "dob": "22/02/1984"
                  },
                  {
                    "email": "j@yahoo.com"
                  },
                  {
                    "phone": "123"
                  }
                ]
                
                
console.log(newArr.map(obj => Object.keys(obj)[0]))
```

Comment: `newArr.reduce((keys, o)  => [...keys, ...Object.keys(o)], [])`, just one pass.

Comment: @dave Thanks. Added your method to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do by looping over the array and using destructuring operator with the desired property name.

```
const arr = [
  {
    nickname: "abdullah"
  },
  {
    age: 27
  }
];

arr.forEach(({nickname}) => {
    if (nickname) {
    console.log(`Thats the property we want to extract: ${nickname}`);
    break; // if you are not expecting this property name in other objects, otherwise no need to break
  }
});
```